# InvalidElementStateException while running Selenium Webdriver with PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm running selenium tests which work OK in Firefox, but I get an error when using PhantomJS.

Here is my python code:

```
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add Province").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_name").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_name").send_keys("Frosinone")
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_code").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_code").send_keys("FR")
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id_name").clear()
self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       InvalidElementStateException: Message: u'Error Message => \'Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated\'\n caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:38159","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"sessionId\\": \\"e0d4d1b0-2f36-11e3-af69-b579903d9fbd\\", \\"id\\": \\":wdc:1381139859399\\"}","url":"/clear","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"clear","directory":"/","path":"/clear","relative":"/clear","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/clear","queryKey":{},"chunks":["clear"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e0d4d1b0-2f36-11e3-af69-b579903d9fbd/element/%3Awdc%3A1381139859399/clear"}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

It is unable to find element `id_name`, yet when run with FireFox, works perfectly.

Anyone knows if there is a current bug with PhantomJS that addresses this issue?

Currently using Selenium 2.35.0 and PhantomJS 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: That's really strange.. Are you sure you're on the same page?

Comment: Yes, I'm on the same page. Various tests including taking of the screenshot confirms so.

Comment: What's the HTML of the element?  It may be that some attribute is tripping up PhantomJS

Comment: `<input type="text" id="id_name" name="name">` I should probably mention that this does not happen on input elements only. It is also unable to click links as well.

Comment: I find this kind of error often happens if the page changes depending on what previous actions you have taken (ie ajax, or changing the interface). If it does, add a wait check of either a) predetermined timeout, or b) (better) wait for element to become present. I do this using a custom function that tries for X seconds to find/interact with an element before failing (only need to do for first element to be tested). I find it occurs in Phantomjs but not a browser because phantom is much quicker

Answer (score 2):

I've used a PhantomJS, ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver for functional testing. **The difference between PhantomJS and others is that PhantomJS driver don't wait for page to be loaded** and returns control to the test program (your python code). Please check this out!

I think this is not a correct behaviour of PhantomJS driver. I found in WebDriver's api documentation:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get(java.lang.String) the following method of WebDriver which opens a given URL

```
void get(java.lang.String url)
```

The description is:

> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done (...) and the method will block until the load is complete.

So it is possible that (and here I agree with @Ashley comment)

- in Firefox a page is fully rendered before test code tries to access an element
- in PhantomJS the test code tries to interact with a page earlier when not yet ready

You can find it easy if you "sleep" your test code for a, let's say, 2 seconds, just before you access first element in your test.

If this is it, you can try to resolve this issue by waiting for page to load (instead of 2 seconds) by checking some condition on your page, e.g. page title should be "My Form". Try it in loop until condition is true. Then run rest of your test.

*Note: You can always take a screenshots, also in headless PhantomJS driver implementation! It will give you a possibility to debug a problem*

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is the field in question truly isn't interactable. PhantomJS isn't telling you it can't find the element, but that it can't interact with it. I had an issue like this (except it was the ChromeDriver), and all I had to do was make the browser window wider.

As promanski suggested, take a screenshot. If your layout is responsive, it's possible the PhantomJS window is narrower than the Firefox one, and causing your element to be rendered hidden. Or set the browser size wider for PhantomJS.

Worth a shot.

Comment: Setting the window size to self.driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) solved this error for me. Maximizing the window would seem to solve as well, but it appears others may have had mixed results.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same trouble. I use selenium and PhantomJS in Python. I'm trying to sign in a webpage, when I use firefox, It always works,but PhantomJS doesn't even if I have "sleep" my code for 60s.The code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='phantomjs.exe')
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://gs.swjtu.edu.cn/ws/gsedu")
time.sleep(60)
form_id = driver.find_element_by_name('userid')
form_id.send_keys('2015xxxxxx')
form_pswd = driver.find_element_by_name("userpwd")
form_pswd.send_keys('xxxxxx99201xxxxxx')
driver.find_element_by_class_name("loginbtn").submit()
print(driver.current_url)
```

I got the error as this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

But when I change a url, PhantomJS works.such as this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='phantomjs.exe')
driver.get("http://www.baidu.com")
driver.find_element_by_id('kw').send_keys('python')
driver.find_element_by_id('su').submit()
print(driver.current_url)
```

then the print is:

> https://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=0&rsv_idx=1&tn=baidu&wd=python&rsv_pq=ceb307010003f0d6&rsv_t=3b72xijigkGFAWp%2FpwxdE0rDAVeegFlzHpa5aXwPD2mBVBRvSQbTKn7Ra%2FQ&rsv_enter=1&rsv_sug3=6&rsv_sug1=1&rsv_sug7=100&inputT=504&rsv_sug4=505

I guess the reason is that some web server deny the request form PhantomJS, accept request from normal clinet. some server not deny.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to clarify how it addresses the question asked here by Frankline instead of how you solved a problem with the code you've provided as part of the answer?

Comment: I got the same error with him. errorMessage:Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Comment: I am using Chrome and got the same error as your said but when changed the web driver into Firefox the code can work nicely. Thank you !~

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue with PhantomJS. I solved it by adding a line to set window size after creating a driver reference as-

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size.
driver.get("http:example.com") # Load page
```

The solution is we need to set a fake browser size before doing browser.get("").

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this right is to check if the it is displayed. `field=driver.find_element_by_id("id_name")
if field.is_displayed():
    field.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem with user-agent changing I set up to phantom js capabilities. Try this [one](https://coderwall.com/p/9jgaeq/set-phantomjs-user-agent-string).